# Magnet script issues in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a magnet PowerUp in Unity. I used this script, which I attached to the coin GameObject:

```
public GameObject attractedTo; 

private float strengthOfAttraction = 3f;

void FixedUpdate ()
    {
    Vector3 direction = attractedTo.transform.position - transform.position;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (strengthOfAttraction * direction);
    }
```

I have two problems :
1. Only newly spawn coins are attracted to the player
2. For some reason, the coins move only in straight lines, so most of them goes past the player

Anyone knows how this can be fixed?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: re1. Add Time.fixedDeltaTime to the multiplication and see what happens. BTW what else do you expect on top of going straight? re2. how do you spawn coins? What code sets the 'attractedTo' field's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major issue on your code. You have to recreate your procedure logic on how you make the coins get closer to the Player.

First Major problem is this.

`void FixedUpdate()` So on a fix amount of time per frame. You are trying to 
Declare a Variable Vector3 : `Vector3 direction = attractedTo.transform.position - transform.position;`

So frame will recalculate and create a new pointer name `direction` then you try to find `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (strengthOfAttraction * direction);`
your Own Component in your gameObject. Then Call Addforce. AddForce. And you didn't even use time.deltatime.

Addforce Will push the rigidbody depending on the direction you input. So it will go straight. And you are doing this Every Fix amount of frame per sec.

First fix your procedure. My recommendation is this.

Use the Smooth Follow script. Made by Unity3D get your Reference there. It is also installed already in the script section in your Editor. If you are having problem finding it, go to this link and check he script.

[Smooth Follow Script](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/smooth-follow-script-to-c-with-some-changes.133158/)

[**Update Answer**]

For the 2nd Problem that only new coins is getting attracted.

Check all of this situations.

1. Your Player is newly spawned and your `attractedTo` variable is blank.
2. Non newly spawned coins should have referenced to the Player already, if not you have to tell all the coins that if you spawn the Player, they needed to be attracted to Player. -> Assign `attractedTo` when Player Spawned.

You can either Achieve that on Instantiate then find all GameObjects with TAG. Then getcomponent then assign `attractedTo`

3. Your non Spawned coins, doesn't have the Script Component.
4. Your non Spawned coins, is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After your suggestion, I tried this : 
    void Update ()
 {  Vector3 direction = attractedTo.position + attractedTo.up * height - attractedTo.forward * distance;

  
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, attractedTo.position, strengthOfAttraction * Time.deltaTime);}

Comment: Now, my 2nd problem is solved but there again, only newly spawn coins are attracted to the player and I don't know why :/

Comment: check Updated Answer

Comment: Alright! I'll try your suggestions! Thanks everyone for your help!